# AWS IAM - How do I deny any actions on resources which have a specific tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to deny all actions on any resource which have a specific tag `Environment: SOME_ENV`. If the resource has another tag value or doesn't have the tag, actions are allowed.

I create this condition:

```
Effect: Deny
Action: '*'
Resource: '*'
Condition:
  StringEquals:
    aws:ResourceTag/Environment: SOME_ENV
```

and also tested with:

```
Condition:
  StringEquals:
    aws:ResourceTag/Environment: SOME_ENV
  'Null':
    aws:ResourceTag/Environment: false
```

The problem is that I may read the Lambda code, tags and everything on the console but I expected that it wasn't possible.

**Considerations:**

I've given view actions (below) and because of this I may view the Lambda code but I may not perform changes, as expected.

```
Sid: 'ViewOnlyActions'
Effect: Allow
Action:
 - lambda:Get*
Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Policy conditions on the [aws:ResourceTag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-resourcetag) key are only relevant to [AWS services that support authorization based on tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html).

AWS Lambda, for one, does not support authorization based on tags at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Its explained very well in these documents

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources-by-using-tags-on-aws-iam-users-and-roles/

Comment: It may indeed be, as you say, explained very well in these documents, but answers on Stack Overflow are expected to actually answer the question being asked, not simply provide links -- see
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/211183.     Please edit this answer to add a complete solution/explanation.

Comment: @Devesh thank you for your reply. The first link states "If the code finds even one explicit deny that applies, the code returns a final decision of Deny" and was that I was expecting, but it didn't work.